# Use outer class in my main.cpp

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, build

I'm using other's class for generating delaunay triangle. Its class has two files: VoronoiDiagramGenerator.h and VoronoiDiagramGenerator.cpp.  It is all encapusulated into a class.

I want to call the class method in my main.cpp file, so I should include the VoronoiDiagramGenerator.h file.

If i want to use gcc or g++, how do I set the cmd parameter? Before I just used gcc -o main.cpp or something similar.

If I want to use makefile, how would I write it?

If I want to compile the two files (VoronoiDiagramGenerator.h && VoronoiDiagramGenerator.cpp) into a So file, how should I do?

I just test the souce code.  When i under windows vc++, add the .cpp and .h into the project workspace, it will be OK. If i just include the .h file in my main file and it give some similar error like linux.

some unreference error.

so i think in my main file just include the out class headfile and  gcc main.cpp is error.

Answer (score 0):

In your `main.cpp` include `VoronoiDiagramGenerator.h` and use it.

If .h file is not in your current or project directory, make sure to include `-Idirectory`

Comment: yes. i did do like this. BUT under ubuntu, it give me some method unrefenced error info. I also use it under windows using vc++. but have no error. So I think there must be some wrong.